# MySQL And PHPMyAdmin Events Scheduler

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, webserver

I've created an iOS and android app that uses a database where users can login which in my case "User_active" gets changes to 1 and logged out gets changed to 0. The only problem I have is that I cannot check to see if the user has left the app, or if they have closed it, so what I want to do is create an event on phpmyadmin to change the "User_active" to 0 after 30min, but I can't seam to get things right. I'm using Awardspace as my host and I've only seen tutorials for localhost. Errors that I'm getting are that my user account does not have the write privileges to create the events and I cannot find any user tabs to change user privileges. If anyone can send me off in the right direction that would be great or even better a solution.

Comment: Are you logged in with root account ? 
or
You should reset the password of mysql for "root"  https://www.howtoforge.com/setting-changing-resetting-mysql-root-passwords and then flush all privileges  and  run grant all privileges mysql command

Comment: I do not know if I'm login at all I'm using Awardspace for hosting and they have a button you push to take you to your database so I have no clue what I'm login as and when ever I try to do anything in the link you provided I get an error "Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation"  and I don't know how to do that as there are no user tabs in phpmyadmin when using awardspace.

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin is a fantastic interactive tool, but it is **not** the tool for this.

In some ways, this is a fairly common problem. Typical web based applications don't know when a user has left, they only know when a user does something. One method is to do the following:

1 - Add a field to the user table (the same table that has the "user_active" field) to track the last activity by that user of any type. This should be a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP field and updated always with the current time.

2 - Add a cronjob to check any records in the user table to see if they are (a) still logged in (user_active=1) **and** the timestamp is more than 30 minutes old. If so, set user_active to 0 - essentially force a logout after 30 minutes. You may want to have an additional field to indicate it was a forced automatic logout rather than a user-initiated logout.

If your hosting service allows cronjobs, then run this periodically (perhaps every 5 minutes) and you are done. If your hosting service doesn't allow cronjobs then one option is to add a call to the "automatic user logout" function as part of every regular page. That won't work if you have thousands of active users as the overhead would be too much (and the delay on each page display). But if you have a small number of active users it will get the job done - I have done plenty of system housekeeping using that method.

Comment: Hi @manassehkatz what you said is exactly what I want to do but the problem I'm having is. the error I get from phpmyadmin is "Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation" I can get this to work on localhost but when I place it on the web in this case I'm using Awardspace to host, all user tabs are not there so I cannot grant the right permissions. Do you know how to fix this. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Devon You shouldn't need CREATE USER privileges, and in fact most hosting companies won't give you CREATE USER privileges, except possibly through a Control Panel (i.e., but not via regular MySQL commands or phpMyAdmin). You should have an assigned MySQL username/password which you use to login to phpMyAdmin and which should work for any normal use - CREATE TABLE, ALTER TABLE, INSERT, DELETE, SELECT, etc. - mysql commands via PHP programs.

Comment: So what you are saying is I cannot create an event with a non localhost phpmyadmin

Comment: No, what I am saying is that the same MySQL user credentials that you use to get into phpMyAdmin can be used with PHP to write a program to do almost anything you want inside a database. phpMyAdmin is an administrative tool - a very powerful one - but it is not designed for automated processing. For that you need a regular language (like PHP which is tagged on this question) to run MySQL commands to do the work, and then you set the PHP code to run as a cronjob.